# Why is my navigation displayed below header?

Tags: css, html, positioning

This is what my page looks like in several browsers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvImY.png
This is how I want it to look across all browsers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSWOY.png

I don't know why it does this. It seems that whatever is wrong, Chrome and Safari interpret it correctly. But Opera always displays my navigation outside of (and below) the header bar. Dreamweaver will also display it that way, but it fixes it if I refresh the page.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Oblique Drive</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <div class="headwrap"><img src="images/logo.png" width="177" height="50" alt="Logo">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="technology.html">TECHNOLOGY</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="company.html">COMPANY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OTHER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RANDOM</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>


<div class="pagewrap">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #7a7a7a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #7a7a7a;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #7a7a7a;
}

.headwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 13px;
}

.logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 147px;
}

nav {
    width: 750px;
    float: right;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}

li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;

}

li a {
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

li a:visited {

}

.pagewrap {
    display: block;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 1500px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    margin-top: 67px;
}

hr {
    border: none;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I've spent all day trying to figure this out and the second I finally post the question on here, I find the answer 2 minutes later. If anyone else is having this issue, or any issue where the html5 "header" and/or "nav" tags are involved, it's an HTML5 interpretation issue. Instead of assigning attributes in your CSS to simply "header" and/or "nav", put the period before to make it a class. In your html give those tags their respective classes, i.e. instead of <header>, use <header class="header">.

Comment: There shouldn't be any 'HTML5 interpretation issue' like this. For all browsers that understand HTML5 tags tag selectors should work. Probably it was a selector specifity issue or just a typo?

Comment: Also, your HTML as is displays fine in my browser (with the nav bar above the line).